# Not getting any results from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql

I have the following procedure interface:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetsItemDetails]
(
    @SiteURL varchar
)
AS

select 
    *
from
    s_ItemDetails
where
    SiteURL = @SiteURL
```

When I call it this way:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetsItemDetails]         @SiteURL =
N'fgh'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I get nothing when there is a record with siteURL "fgh"

Comment: but i want to get all columns as output tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to specify the size of the parameter.

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetsItemDetails]
(
    @SiteURL varchar
)
AS
```

Without size it is 1 character.

Specify the same size as your columns size for `SiteURL`.

Something like this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetsItemDetails]
(
    @SiteURL varchar(255)
)
AS
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetsItemDetails]
(
    @SiteURL varchar(1000)
)
AS
DECLARE @str varchar(1000)
SET @str='select * from s_ItemDetails where  SiteURL ='+ ''''+@SiteURL+''''
select @str
```